# AJAX response returns "success" but can't compare it correctly

Tags: php, ajax

I am having some issues with an AJAX call. AJAX is being used to update a row in a table, then either "success" or "failure" is returned from the PHP file. The response is then checked within AJAX to see if "success" or "failure" was received, this is the part that is giving me trouble.

This is done by checking if the response is equal to "success" or "failure" as follows:

```
    // Called on success
    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        if (response == "success") {
            $("#register-vehicle-message-failure").css('display', 'none');
            $("#register-vehicle-message-success").css('display', 'block');
            $("#register-vehicle-text-success").html("SUCCESS");
        } else if (response == "failure") {
            $("#register-vehicle-message-success").css('display', 'none');
            $("#register-vehicle-message-failure").css('display', 'block');
            $("#register-vehicle-text-failure").html("FAILURE");
        }
    });
```

Basically a message should be displayed to indicate if it was successful or not, however neither message is being shown.

I tried something else later on which showed some results. I replace the 'else if' with just 'else' and the code in the 'else block' started running.

```
    // Called on success
    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        if (response == "success") {
            $("#register-vehicle-message-failure").css('display', 'none');
            $("#register-vehicle-message-success").css('display', 'block');
            $("#register-vehicle-text-success").html("HEY");
        } else {
            $("#register-vehicle-message-success").css('display', 'none');
            $("#register-vehicle-message-failure").css('display', 'block');
            $("#register-vehicle-text-failure").html(response);
        }
    });
```

This resulted in always running the code in the 'else' block, no matter if the row was updated or not. I have also changed the html of the text to show the response (last line in else block), and the response being displayed there is actually correct!

If the row changes successfully, then the 'if (response == "success")' comparison won't work, BUT the code in the 'else block' runs and it shows the message "success" (response from ajax). The same is done if a row fails to update, where "failure" is displayed as a message instead.

So since I'm receiving the correct response from the PHP file (success or failure), then I assume that the issue is with the comparison being made. Does anyone how this can be fixed? Thanks.

Full PHP Code

```
<?php

require_once('validation_util.php');
session_start(); // - Begin session

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    if (isset($_POST['register_iccid']))
    {
        // Retrieve the data inputted by a registering user and sanitize + format the data
        $iccid = sanitizeData($_POST['register_iccid']);


        require_once 'dbconnect.php';
        $conn = getConnection(); // - Connect to DB

        $user_id = 0;

        // Store the user's ID (must be logged in via session or cookie)
        if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
            $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        else if (isset($_COOKIE['remember_user']))
            $user_id = $_COOKIE['remember_user'];

        $sqlstatement = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `vehicles` SET `owner_id` = :owner_id WHERE `vehicle_iccid` = :iccid");
        // Bind the values
        $sqlstatement->bindValue(':owner_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sqlstatement->bindValue(':iccid', $iccid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sqlstatement->execute();

        // If a row is returned (Only 1 row should be returned)
        if ($sqlstatement->rowCount() == 1)
            echo "success";
        else
            echo "failure";

        $conn = null; // - Close connection
    }
}

?>
```

This will echo either 'success' or 'failure' to show if the sql update was successful.

Full AJAX Code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var request; // - Ajax request

    $('#register-vehicle-form').submit(function (e) {
        // Abort any pending requests
        if (request) {
            request.abort();
        }

        var url = "../php/vehicle_registration.php"; // - Php file path to request from
        var $form = $(this); // - Store form in var
        var $fields = $form.find("input");

        // Serialize form data
        var serializedData = $form.serialize();

        // Disable form elements (after the form data has been serialized)
        $fields.prop("disabled", true);

        // Fire the request to vehicle_registration.php file
        request = $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "post",
            data: serializedData
        });

        // Called on success
        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (response == "success") {
                $("#register-vehicle-message-failure").css('display', 'none');
                $("#register-vehicle-message-success").css('display', 'block');
                $("#register-vehicle-text-success").html("SUCCESS");
            } else {
                $("#register-vehicle-message-success").css('display', 'none');
                $("#register-vehicle-message-failure").css('display', 'block');
                $("#register-vehicle-text-failure").html(response);
            }
        });

        // Called on failure
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.error("Error: " + textStatus, errorThrown);
        });

        // Called always
        request.always(function () {
            $fields.prop("disabled", false); // - Re-enable the input fields
        });

        // Prevent default behaviour of form, so we can submit it here
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Do a `console.log(response);`  there may be something in there you're not expecting.

Comment: The text probably needs to be trimmed.

Comment: What if you `console.log()` or `alert()`  `response` in `response.done()`? What's the output? Maybe it doesn't match any of your conditions.

Comment: Why don't you try regex to search if the string contains "success"? try `if preg_match('/^success/',response)`

Comment: Thank you @RocketHazmat ! I should have tried that in the beginning.

The problem was actually a commented line (CSS comment style) above my PHP code that I failed to see inside my PHP file. Quite the silly mistake.

Also thank you to all the others who have also given their suggestions, it is very much appreciated.